# Subset rows within one predictor in GLM without disturb other

Tags: r, subset, glm, lm, stat

I fit parasitoid abundance to two factors, flower availability and distance of the crop to flower.

Firstly, I fit separate glm equation:

```
glm(abundance ~ flower, data = data, family = poisson(link"log"))
```

which in this case, `flower` had two classes: `"yes"` and `"no"` the class "no" here regarded as control.

Then I fit `abundance ~ distance`

The `data$distance` had three classes (0,10,
and 20), but in dataframe, this column contains additional classes from `data$flower= "no"` .

Consequently, I eliminated the rows containing `flower = "No"` (or control) by subsetting it, because it not make sense for me to include the distance observation from control data,

```
glm(abundance ~ distance, data = data, family = poisson(link"log"),
    subset = flower != "No")
```

The problem arises when I try to merge both factors into a single glm equation:

```
glm(abundance ~ flower + distance, data = data, family = poisson(link"log"))
```

how to pass the  `subset = flower != "No"` , only to the variable `data$distance` without disturb other factor?

any suggestion?

Comment: I do not understand. Is this possible? You could generate synthetic data if certain factor combinations are only present for `flower == "No"`.

Comment: This is the wrong approach to the problem; it doesn't make sense to subset only a single variable, since the vectors used must all be the same length. If you want an estimate for both the presence of a flower _and_ the effect of distance, then you can convert `flower` to a binary variable using `data$flower <- as.numeric(data$flower == "yes")`.  Then give all distances with no flower a value of 0 using `data$distance[data$flower == 0] <- 0`. Then your model will be `glm(abundance ~ flower + distance:flower, data = data)`. You will get estimates for flower presence and distance.

Comment: `poisson(link"log")` throws an error.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and suggestion, Friede and Allan_Cameron, I will go on this approach. Could you make this as an answer?